Efficient prediction using Lightgbm/XGBoost when varying single feature keeping the remaining constant
Assume we have a pre-trained Lightgbm/XGBoost model $f$ dependent on the feature matrix:
$$X=\left[z, C\right]$$
Here $z$ is a single feature column and $C$ is the remaining feature columns. I need to do prediction for a huge amount of different $z$ vectors: $z_1,...,z_S$, while the remaining features $C$ stays constant. The length of $z_s$ is always the same for all $s$ and (obviously) equal to the number of rows in $C$.
$$f\left(\left[z_s, C\right]\right) \quad s=1,...,S$$
I am looking for method to utilize that $C$ is fixed to decrease the computational time of prediction. I have looked at daal4py. While this does make the prediction faster I suspect even better performance can be obtained by somehow utilizing $C$ stays constant.
The code below illustrates the problem using a toy-dataset. In practice the dataset will be much larger.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb
import time
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes

# Data
diabetes = load_diabetes()
y = diabetes.target
C = pd.DataFrame(diabetes.data[:,:-1], columns=diabetes.feature_names[:-1])
z = pd.Series(diabetes.data[:,-1], name=diabetes.feature_names[-1])
X = pd.concat([z, C], axis=1)

# "Pre"-trained model
model = lgb.LGBMRegressor().fit(X, y)

# Model for prediction
model_z = lambda z: model.predict(np.c_[z, C])

# Prediction
S = 10000
Z = np.random.normal(loc=z.mean(), scale=z.std(), size=(len(z), S))

t0 = time.time()
results = [model_z(Z[:,s]) for s in np.arange(0,S)] 
t1 = time.time()

total_time = t1-t0 # This needs to be reduced
print(f"Computation time: {total_time}")


The problem is that in principle, boosting can model any kind of interaction between your fixed $C$ and your varying $z$, so even if $C$ is fixed, its particular setting may have any impact on the response as a function of $z$ that you like... so in principle, you may need to traverse the entire boosted tree for each new value of $z$.
One possibility for a speedup is of course to store your previous results and retrieve them if you see a $z$ you already saw (and evaluated) before. This can be helpful if your $z$ candidates contain many duplicates.
If this is not helpful, then you could speed things up by sampling a small proportion of your $z$s, fitting a "helper" model to these evaluations, and then evaluating this helper model instead of your "big" one. This may speed matters up tremendously. However, of course this is only an approximation to your original model.
You may be able to leverage domain knowledge to give bounds on the interpolation error. But again, in principle since a general boosting model can fit any relationship, there can be no such bounds "in general", even assuming $C$ constant.
